# Upper bound for measure of given set.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

in an answer to a different question this equation, which I don't quite follow, was used:

for $x\in \mathbb{R}: 
m(E_q)=m\left(\{x\in [0,1] \mid |x-\frac{p}{q}| \leq \frac{1}{q^3}\text{ for some  }0\leq p \leq q\}\right)\leq q\cdot q^3$ with $p$ and $q$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ and coprime. Here the measure $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Could somebody explain how they arrived at this upper bound for the measure of the set? Thanks in advance!

---

In case it is needed the question was: Show that the set of $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that there are infinitely many $\frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q$ relatively prime and $|x-\frac{p}{q}|\leq \frac{1}{q^3}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.

Comment: Apparently $m(E_q)\le 1$, as $E_q\subset [0,1]$. Thus the inequality you want to understand is trivial - unless of course you made a mistake in the bound. Did you mean that $m(E_q)\le 1/q^2$?

Comment: No, when I was doing the equation I thought it was $1/q^3$ but the solutions stated the above bound. There could of course be a mistake in the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Something appears to be wrong with your bounds; but the problem can be solved as follows.

Note that
$$
E_q = \bigcup_{p \leq q, (p,q)=1} \left\lbrace x\in [0,1] : |x-\frac{p}{q}| \leq \frac{1}{q^3} \right\rbrace
$$

For a fixed $p \in \{0,1,2,\ldots, q\}$,
$$
|x-\frac{p}{q}| \leq \frac{1}{q^3} \Leftrightarrow \frac{p}{q} - \frac{1}{q^3} \leq x \leq \frac{p}{q} + \frac{1}{q^3}
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow \frac{pq^2-1}{q^3} \leq x \leq \frac{pq^2+1}{q^3}
$$
And the measure of the interval
$$
m\left[ \frac{pq^2-1}{q^3}, \frac{pq^2+1}{q^3}\right] = \frac{2}{q^3}
$$
Hence,
$$
m(E_q) \leq \frac{2\varphi(q)}{q^3} \leq \frac{2}{q^2}
$$

---

To answer your second question, suppose $|x-p/q|$ for infinitely many pairs $(p,q)$ as above, then $x\in E_q$ for infinitely many $q\in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence,
$$
x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{q=n}^{\infty} E_q
$$
Since
$$
\sum_{q=1}^{\infty} m(E_q) <\infty
$$
By the [Borel-Cantelli Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma),
$$
m\left ( \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{q=n}^{\infty} E_q\right) = 0
$$
which is what you want to prove.

Comment: Could you explain what $\phi(q)$ is? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function As it turns out, you don't need it for this problem though. You just need the weaker bound of $2/q^2$

Comment: aah! thank you so much!